# Using speech to text in bluemix and storing in database

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, cloudant

I am using the sample app of speech to text: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs

How can I store the generated text to Cloudant NoSQL Database?

Thanks in advance.